# ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code. razor MVC 4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

What i did is following:

```
@{var parent = new BlogCommentModel();}
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{

@foreach (var child in Model.Comments.Where(x => x.CommentParentID == comment.Id))
{

if (child.ChildCommentList!= null || child.ChildCommentList.Any())
{
parent = child;

foreach (var cmt in parent.ChildCommentList)
{

}

}

}
```

when ChildCommentList is null. it is throw an exception :

ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code. - {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}

Comment: @flem: Yes. For few comments there are not childcomments.

Answer (score 2):

You should use AND operator on the line below.

```
if (child.ChildCommentList!= null && child.ChildCommentList.Any())
```

Comment: Its still fired and exception.

Comment: @NetraSW Which line exactly?

Comment: on if (child.ChildCommentList!= null || child.ChildCommentList.Any())

Comment: @NetraSW have you changed it to use AND operator like above?